# Vue: Change class with the value of a variable in setInterval

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties

I am learning Vue JS. I want to change class using `setInterval`. But can’t pass the changing value of `Method` to `Computed Property`. After two seconds class will change automatically with the changed value of "`changeColor`"

My Code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button @click="startEffect">Start Effect</button>
    <div id="effect" :class="myClass"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px !important;
}

.shrink {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 50px !important;
}
```

Vue JS:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#exercise',
    data: {
        changeColor: false
    },

    methods : {
        startEffect: function() {
            setInterval(function(){
                 this.changeColor = !this.changeColor;
                 //alert(this.changeColor);
            }, 2000);

            //alert(this.changeColor);
        }
    },

    computed: {
        myClass: function() {
            return {
                highlight: this.changeColor,
                shrink: !this.changeColor
          }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use setInterval in vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335477/how-to-use-setinterval-in-vue-component)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

bind your function to the component...

```
 setInterval(function(){
                 this.changeColor = !this.changeColor;         
            }.bind(this), 2000);
```

and then you can do ...

```
<div id="effect" :class="[changeColor?'highlight':'shrink']"></div>
```