# How to define `setInterval` in the scope of specific component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, quasar-framework

I want to run `setInterval` just in the scope of a specific component (limit to that component not the whole of application) because I'm using SPA mode by Quasar framework.

When I set this function it causes run in everywhere even I changed the page's URL.
Also, I checked this [link (how to use setInterval in Vue component)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335477/how-to-use-setinterval-in-vue-component) but it wasn't my answer.

My sample code:

```
methods:
  testInterval: function () {
    setInterval(() => this.playCMD(), 2000)
  },
  playCMD: function () {
    // Do something
    console.log('Do something')
  }
```

Also, it's better to say I want to limit doing something in the specific scope in VueJs, not in the whole of the application when we use it through SPA mode.

Comment: Can you elaborate. What does it mean "it causes run everywhere" ?

Comment: @ajobi I want to stop the setInterval function when I change my page in SPA mode, in another word I want to finish setInterval when the process of that page is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shoejep thank you so much, It works. we had to add `next()` function into `beforeRouteLeave`. Please see below:

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    if(this.timer)
        clearInterval(this.timer)
        next()
}
```

Because if we do not put the `next()` into that function we can't go to another routes.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used the Quasar framework but you could try these options:

1. Subscribing to the [Vue lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) 'destroyed' event and then do a clearTimeout.

Or

2. If you're using Vue-Router you can use [In-Component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) which are events when you navigate to another component, which you could use to do a clearTimeout.

   ```
    data: () => {
        return {
            timer: null
        };
    },
    methods: {
        testInterval() {
            this.timer = setInterval(this.playCMD, 2000)
        }
    },
    beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
        if(this.timer)
            clearInterval(this.timer);
        next();
    }
   ```

EDIT: Thanks @Ali Hallaji. You have to add a call to the next function to proceed through the pipeline, as described [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guard).

Comment: I would go with the first option -> lifecycle hooks. I have a suspicion that there would be a leak happening if you would destroy the component, but not necessarily change the route (for example with conditional rendering with v-if)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find much documentation for your use case, only [this](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-ssr/writing-universal-code#Component-Lifecycle-Hooks) incase you're using SSR. You could also try the 'beforeDestory' event instead of 'destroyed', or as a last resort you could pass the route to the function and then compare if it's equal to the current route.